# Can you actually build and deploy a Ubuntu virtual machine through Azure DevOps?

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, packer

Apologies to those who understand Azure DevOps easily. I've been poking at this for a few weeks now and I can't seem to grasp the full concept.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Commit to Github to set off a build and deployment in Azure DevOps

  - Contains a packer.json configuration
  - Contains an azure-pipelines.yml configuration
- Resources have been defined in Azure Portal
- Pipeline has been configured and builds when repo is pushed to
- Deployment fails in 'Releases' fails, usually relating to the artifact

First off... can I actually build a Ubuntu image with packer, then automagically release that image as a virtual machine?

I keep seeing references to ARM templates, which I haven't gotten into at this point. My main problem (I believe) is that I'm not targeting the artifact correctly or under the wrong impression of *which* target I should be going after.

My yaml is out of wack and the deployment process is shotty at best. I've also tried creating something in DevOps and I'm still lost on what I'm suppose to be choosing. It seems like every reference I find is older and even many of those show an old version of all the screens.

Is there any guidance you can provide? I can't seem to hone in on my main issue... whether that's a configuration issue within DevOps or if I'm breaking my yaml (I've tried a few targets in the last task and they usually just fail on me. Tried the packer.json and azure-pipelines.yml files, but that doesn't seem right).

I also keep seeing reference to people setting up the resources, actually using packer to create the vm in Azure, then using DevOps to deploy the VM... but I'm trying to do it all from a commit kickoff.

My yaml pretty much looks like the following (I'm guessing some of that stuff is not necessary):

```
trigger:
  batch: true

name: $(BuildID)

variables:
  - group: azure-packer-vars
  - group: azure-packer-secrets

stages:
- stage: ubuntu_18_04_lts
  displayName: Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS
  jobs:
  - job: build
    displayName: Build Image
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
    - task: riezebosch.Packer.PackerTool.PackerTool@0
      displayName: 'Use Packer 1.5.6'
      inputs:
        version: 1.5.6
    - task: PackerBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build Image'
      inputs:
        imageUri: 'BuildImage'        
        templateType: 'custom'
        customTemplateLocation: 'packer.json'
        customTemplateParameters:
          '{"ClientAppId":"$(ClientAppId)",
          "ClientAppSecret":"$(ClientAppSecret)",
          "TenantId":"$(TenantId)",
          "SubscriptionId":"$(SubscriptionId)",
          "ImageDestRG":"$(ImageDestRG)",
          "TempResourceGroup":"$(TempResourceGroup)",
          "VirtualNetwork":"$(VirtualNetwork)",
          "VirtualNetworkRG":"$(VirtualNetworkRG)",
          "VirtualSubnet":"$(VirtualSubnet)",
          "Location":"$(Location)",
          "VMSize":"$(VMSize)",
          "StorageName":"$(StorageName)",
          "StorageKey":"$(StorageKey)",
          "StorageInstallerPath":"$(StorageInstallerPath)",
          "Build_BuildNumber":"$(Build.BuildNumber)",
          "Build_DefinitionName":"$(Build.DefinitionName)"}'
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Build Image and associated Template'
      inputs:
        artifactName: BuildOutput
        pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
        artifact: 'packer.json'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an official M$ guide: [How to use Packer to create Linux virtual machine images in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/build-image-with-packer). The process is as follows:

1. Create a json description of your VM for Packer, set it to use `azure-arm`  builder (seems you already have that).
2. Run packer with that json file. It will spin up a VM, run provisioners, and create a Managed Azure Image from that. The image is stored in Azure (you specify the resource group and name for that image in json file). The VM is then removed and all you're left with is that image. (I guess `PackerBuild@1` in your pipeline does that).
3. Create a new VM, from that stored image. The guide mentions `az vm create` and you can use [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) in your pipeline - this is the step you're missing.

You shouldn't need any artifact tasks in there - artifacts are just files attached to specific pipeline run, they do not do any actual deployment. The image will be rather large and is stored in Azure anyway, so it doesn't make sense to copy it over to DevOps.

It's also a good idea to first do everything from command line, on your local machine. Once you achieve what you want, you'll have a list of steps (and commands) that your pipeline should execute. Then convert this list to pipeline steps - some of them may have specific tasks (like `PackerBuild`), some will be just generic `script` tasks.

Comment: Thank you @qbik. I've taken that step before while I was figuring out the rest, but does that mean there's no way to creat the virtual machine through the pipeline directly without creating it manually the first time?